# What is hints parameter for getaddrinfo?

Tags: sockets, getaddrinfo

I can't understand usage for `hints` parameter in `getaddrinfo()`

```
getaddrinfo(node, service, &hints, &res);
```

Same sample code for `getadderinfo()` like below doesn't read `hints` as if `hints`’ll never be set value.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getaddrinfo&sektion=3

Then what is `hints` for ?

Do I have to check the value of the `hints` when `getaddrinfo` returns?

Comment: What part of "The hints parameter specifies the preferred socket type,  or  protocol" don't you understand?

Comment: Now I understand. I must have read carefully.　The hitnts is kind of switch to change behavior of `getaddrinfo()`, not the parameter for accepting returned value.